# What is the multi-label binary classification?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, loss

Reading PyTorch docs  [BCEWithLogitsLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html):

> where c is the class number (c > 1 for multi-label binary classification, c = 1 for single-label binary classification), nn is the number of the sample in the batch and p_cp 
>   c is the weight of the positive answer for the class cc .

What is the **multi-label** binary classification? Binary assume only two labels AFIK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multi-label in terms of binary classification means that both the classes can be true class for a single example.

For example, in case of dog-cat classifier, for an image containing both dog and cat, it'll predict both dog and cat.

> In the multi-label problem there is no constraint on how many of the classes the instance can be assigned to. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification)